# YA book series kids on a spaceship called "Mother"

Tags: story-identification

I read a book series about 15 years ago when I was a young kid, and I believe there was at least 7 books in the series. I remembered them being sorta short in length (around the size of an R.L.Stine YA book) and each book was paperback with a glossy photo/image type cover so I believe the series was sort of new, Year 2000+. The first cover book had a blue hue and a kid was laying down with some sort of thick tubing going into his head. The series was in English.

Since I was pretty young when I read it, my memories of it are pretty faint now. But what I do remember is that something was going to happen to the earth so they sent people into space in a ship in hibernation pods to wait out whatever happened.

There were kids and teens, very few adults (if any) and when they woke up they were trying to figure out what happened.

In one of the books I know they somehow got back to earth and it was pretty uninhabitable (I think). What sticks out to me most is that the spaceship's mainframe or central computing system called itself mother. It could rearrange the environment and space inside the craft for super large distances (kinda like mini world).

For some reason Mother was actually bad or something (perhaps not letting them leave the ship/environment) so they plotted a way to kill her or escape. I think the kids on the space ended up splitting into groups at one point, and some of them may have developed some sort of psychic power. One scene I can remember is them running over a grassy field in the simulated world that Mother made.

I know that Alien has a spaceship called Mother, but this definitely isn't it.

**Edit**

I'm pretty positive the author's name was two initials and a last name. Can't remember the letters or the last name though.

Comment: The one in Aliens is MU-TH-UR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably K.A. Applegates *[Remnants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remnants_(novel_series))* series.

[image: Remnants - Book Cover]

> Remnants is a series of science fiction books written by K. A. Applegate between July 2001 and September 2003. It is the story of what happens to the survivors of a desperate mission to save a handful of human beings after an asteroid collides with the Earth. Eighty people are placed aboard a converted space shuttle using untested "quack" hibernation technology and fired blindly into space hours before all life on Earth is obliterated by a large asteroid called The Rock. They are then picked up by a large, sentient space craft of monumental proportions known as 'Mother' which is inhabited by various races. 'Mother' can manipulate the physical environment within the craft's limits and often does so. Only a few people placed in stasis actually were alive and capable of being reanimated when they reached 'Mother'.

Your clue about the name of the author made me immediately think of Applegate, and I remembered the basic plot of the books from prior times it was the answer. Then, it was a matter of verifying it via a quick Google search and noting that the cover also matched.

Comment: Yep that's it for sure. I searched a few different combos for past questions and didn't come across it, so whoops! But thanks!